# Why there are 50~60% questions with accepted answers in nearly all important categories?

Tags: discussion

I have recently made a [simple website](http://stackcomparison.vanisoft.pl/), which compares various frameworks/languages etc. based on fraction of questions with accepted answers (using "hasaccepted:yes" search query condition). What immediately became obvious is that most popular topics seem to have very similar ratio: roughly 50-60%.
There are several possible explanations of this phenomenon that came to my mind:

1. There is a bug in my service. I ruled that out, by manually checking several queries.
2. There is a bug in stackoverflow's search engine. (I don't believe it)
3. There is some natural tendency in humans to stop asking questions once X previously asked questions are ignored. (That would not explain much without some additional assumptions about the process).
4. There is something in the GUI/notifications/main page, which causes feedback and stabilization - for example maybe topics with <50% answeres get promoted to main page?

What is the real explanation of this convergence?

Comment: There are total of 6,068,736 questions on Stack Overflow at the moment. 1,398,164 questions does not have upvoted answers. That means 4,670,572 questions have at least one answer which is upvoted and it's 76.96% ratio. Your math is wrong.

Comment: As pointed out by @Sha there, your issue is that you have the definition of answered wrong.

Comment: I've restated to question to make it clear which definition I use, and what I want to know

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Do you mean an answer with >= 1 upvotes, or an answer with a net score >= 1?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName well, it says "questions with no upvoted answers" so taking it as-is it should mean 1 upvote is enough even if there are 10 downvotes. But considering the past, it might be misleading text and actually means it need net score of 1. Feel free to ask in a new question, didn't find any such existing question now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "well, it says" - what is it? I don't know offhand the source of your numbers and didn't see them on the SO main page, SO page for SEDE, or OP's website.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName it's written [here in the Unanswered Questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) on Stack Overflow. (and as tooltip in the "unanswered" tab of the main [Questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions))

Answer (score 12):

Looking at [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

- [479,936 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion)
- [458,280 open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse)
- [286,097 have an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+hasaccepted%3Ayes)
- [416,296 have at least one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+answers%3A1)

That means 62.4% accepted, 90.8% answered.

There is no problem here unless you consider a question without an accepted answer to be "unanswered" (that usually isn't the case). [20k of those 130k questions without an accepted answer have more than 5 answers on them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+answers%3A5+hasaccepted%3Ayes). [90k have 3 or more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+answers%3A3+hasaccepted%3Ayes).

The issue that you are struggling with is the general accept rate of SO in general.

There are [5,829,277 open questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse). [3,478,426 have accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+hasaccepted%3Atrue). That is around 60%. This is not related to popular tags, it's just the nature of the beast.

Comment: The answered definition that [SO] uses is a question has at least one upvoted answer. So your 90.8% number (while correct) doesn't match what the website calls answered (which is 78.7% answered - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers)

Answer (score 1):

A more likely explanation than those you've given is the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). If we assume that the probability of a user accepting an answer to their question is independent of the tags on the question, then the accept rate on a tag with a large number of questions will be close to the global accept rate with a very large probability.

This assumption is not 100% true, which is probably why you still saw a 10% variance. For example, some tags may draw users who tend to accept more or less answers than others. But the dependence between tag and accept rate is probably not high, as evidenced by the results, and I would be surprised if it was different.

Comment: Big factor is long time users who ask lots of questions. They usually accept answers to their questions, even if just to help themselves get more help. The accept rate of the "one time askers" is much much lower than 50% and I'll take a wild guess that it's somewhere between 10% and 20%.

Comment: Your answer is totally correct, but also not really explaining the situation, as it restates my observation as your assumption :) It raises even more questions : why it is 60% and not 40, or 90? why is acceptance rate independent of topic? is it because people give up banging head over keyboard and post question on SO raughly at the same "diffulty threshold" regardless of topic, or is it because SO routes traffic in a specific way? or is there some external selection pressure on languages and technologies which removes too difficult from the market?

Comment: @qbolec: As I said, I would be surprised if the two factors were not mostly independent. Why would you think they aren't?  A question is a question, I don't see why someone asking a Java question should be more or less likely to accept an answer than someone asking a C# question.

Comment: And as for why 60% and not 40%: You could ask that about any number. You won't get a meaningful answer here (other than pure conjecture) unless someone conducts a poll asking users why they did or didn't accept an answer.